# Extract required bytes from a file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, binary, scipy

I have a binary file here:
ftp://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SAN/GLAS/GLA06.034/2003.02.21/GLA06_634_1102_001_0079_3_01_0001.DAT

I have to extract the following data from that file:

```
Byte Offset: 176 
Data type: 4-byte (long) integer
Total bytes: 160
```

I tried as follows:

```
import numpy as np    
fname = 'GLA06_634_1102_001_0079_3_01_0001.DAT' 

with open(fname,'rb') as fi:
    fi.seek (176,0)
    data= np.fromfile(fi,dtype='long',count=160)
    print data
```

No success, what's wrong with my idea?

Comment: Do you want to print the value in place 176? it's not so clear what do you want to do.

Comment: No, I want to get the actual datasets specified by byte offset and data size

Comment: 176 is byte offsets, after that offsets in the file the required data exists

Comment: Which value do you want from the file? it will be much easier.

Comment: The values are in long integer formats, its not one but are set of numbers. The variable name is i_lat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a *hard coded* offset is a rather *fragile* solution. But assuming you know what you are doing:

```
Byte Offset: 176 
Data type: 4-byte (long) integer
Total bytes: 160
```

AKAICT, that leads to 160/4 = **40** values to read (could you confirm that?)

In addition, the type should be one of the numpy defined type. Here `np.int32` might be the right one:

```
data= np.fromfile(fi,dtype=np.int32,count=40)
```

On my computer, this produces the following result:

```
[1919251297  997485633 1634494218 1936678771 1634885475  825124212
  808333629  808464432  942813232 1818692155 1868526433 1918854003
 1600484449 1702125924  842871086  758329392  841822768 1728723760
 1601397100 1600353135 1702125938 1835627615 1026633317  809119792
  808466992 1668483643 1668509535 1952543327 1026633317  960048688
  960051513  909654073  926037812 1668483643 1668509535 1952543327
 1633967973  825124212  808464957  842018099]
```

---

If this is not what expected, maybe you have a problem of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Numpy as support for [custom defined types](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructin) to solve that problem:

For example:

- `np.dtype('<i4')` is 4 bytes (signed) integer *little endian*
- `np.dtype('>i4')` is 4 bytes (signed) integer *big endian*

In you case, to force reading data as little endian, you might write:

```
dt = np.dtype('<i4')

with open(fname,'rb') as fi:
    fi.seek (176,0)
    data= np.fromfile(fi,dtype=dt,count=40)
    print data
```

Comment: Thansk for your efforts. I think the header file should be scaped before this

Comment: The required values are not only 40, they are much more

Comment: _"required values are not only 40, they are much more"_ So your total byte is wrong. Or there is something I don't unserstand as "160 bytes / 4 bytes par value" _is_ "40 values". For the endianness, see my edit.

Comment: The expected data inside the file are 15312.

Comment: They are like this: -50.356519
-50.35806
-50.361143
-50.362686
-50.364229
-50.365772
-50.370389
-50.371925
-64.969675
-64.9712
-64.972726
-64.997073
-64.998594

Comment: If you are interested, here is documentation for the binary file http://nsidc.org/data/docs/daac/glas_altimetry/gla14_records_r34.html

Comment: Since your question has provided lots of information for me inspite of complete solution, I have accepted it; would +1 if I had >15 points.