# get number of header lines beforehand

Tags: python

I have a binary file which consist of header lines and the binary parts.  ftp://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SAN/GLAS/GLA06.034/2003.02.21/GLA06_634_1102_001_0079_3_01_0001.DAT

I have to know the number of lines occupied by the header lines. How can I know it before hand so that I could put the value below in order to escape the header parts.

```
import numpy as np    
fname = 'GLA06_634_1102_001_0079_3_01_0001.DAT' 

with open(fname,'rb') as fi:
    fi.seek (176,0) ##HERE I HAVE TO PUT
```

Comment: Is there any header format so that one can decide when the header starts/finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the provided [read file routine](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/icesat/tools/idl/reader/isips/IDLreadGLAS_20140731/read_glas_file.pro):

```
n_headers = long( read_header( i_file, 'NUMHEAD', error=error) )
recl= long( read_header( i_file, 'RECL', error=error) )
offset=long(recl*n_headers)
print,'offset=',offset
print,'recl   n_headers = ',recl,n_headers
str_vers = 'pv'+strtrim(string(ver1),2)+'_'+ $
             strtrim(string(ver2),2)
print, 'version=',str_vers
```

It appears that the header size is `recl*n_headers` where those two value are the first two headers. So:

```
fname = 'GLA06_634_1102_001_0079_3_01_0001.DAT'

with open(fname,'rb') as fi:
    recl = None
    numhead = None

    # Loop in case the required headers are not the first two one
    # and/or in wrong order
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith('Recl='):
            recl = int(line[5:-2])
        if line.startswith('Numhead='):
            numhead = int(line[8:-2])

        if recl is not None and numhead is not None:
            break

    offset = recl*numhead

    print "Binary data starts at ", offset
    fi.seek(offset)
```

Comment: wahoo! this is the exact way to get 13760, i.e., header offsets, thanks++

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's a blank line separating the text from binary:

```
skiprows = 0
for line in open(file):
    if line != '\n'
        skiprows += 1
    else:
        break

with open(fname, 'rb') as fi:
    fi.seek(skiprows, 0)
```

Comment: _"Assuming that's a blank line separating the text from binary:"_ the OP will confirm, but it doesn't seems to me.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux I also do not know because it is my trial to get the data as I asked yesterday in my previous question because of complex nature of the binary file perhaps. But this answer provides at least general solution (the assumption as you mentioned), so have accepted it.

Comment: It looks like there is a blank line after "gASP_t2= 99100800.0000000;". That's what my assumption is about the data.

Comment: @chrisaycock just to ask if you are familiar with this type of problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404619/extract-required-bytes-from-a-file-in-python

Comment: @chrisaycock Strange, as the hexdump shows a line of 'spaces' as the last line of the header. Not an empty line.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yeah, your answer is a lot better.

Comment: unfortunately going to accept more better answer, sorry.

Comment: @puti No need to apologize. Sylvain did a lot more work than I did to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, an hexdump of your file shows that "binary data" *seems* to start at 0x35c0:

```
00001a20  39 3b 0a 67 41 53 50 5f  74 31 3d 20 39 39 30 37  |9;.gASP_t1= 9907|
00001a30  39 32 30 30 2e 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 3b 0a 67 6c  |9200.0000000;.gl|
00001a40  6f 62 41 76 53 72 66 50  72 65 73 32 3d 20 38 39  |obAvSrfPres2= 89|
00001a50  30 35 38 2e 39 35 32 33  36 33 37 3b 0a 67 41 53  |058.9523637;.gAS|
00001a60  50 5f 74 32 3d 20 39 39  31 30 30 38 30 30 2e 30  |P_t2= 99100800.0|
00001a70  30 30 30 30 30 30 3b 0a  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |000000;.        |
00001a80  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
*
00001ae0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000035c0  01 53 05 b0 05 e8 11 30  00 01 0a de 08 0b 00 00  |.S.....0........|
000035d0  ff ff ff 52 00 00 61 a8  00 00 c3 50 00 01 24 f8  |...R..a....P..$.|
000035e0  00 01 86 a0 00 01 e8 48  00 02 49 f0 00 02 ab 98  |.......H..I.....|
000035f0  00 03 0d 40 00 03 6e e8  00 03 d0 90 00 04 32 38  |...@..n.......28|
00003600  00 04 93 e0 00 04 f5 88  00 05 57 30 00 05 b8 d8  |..........W0....|
00003610  00 06 1a 80 00 06 7c 28  00 06 dd d0 00 07 3f 78  |......|(......?x|
00003620  00 07 a1 20 00 08 02 c8  00 08 64 70 00 08 c6 18  |... ......dp....|
```

*Apparently*, the binary data are preceded by a bunch of `0x00`. As an heuristic, we might try to locate that part:

```
fname = 'GLA06_634_1102_001_0079_3_01_0001.DAT'

with open(fname,'rb') as fi:
    while fi.read(1) != b'\x00': # skip text part
        pass
    while fi.read(1) == b'\x00': # skip 0x00
        pass

    # rewind 1 byte
    fi.seek(fi.tell()-1)

    print "Binary data starts at ", fi.tell()
```

Some words of warning:

- You definitively should add some "error handling" here.
- This is rather fragile as I don't know anything about that format.
- Can't you find some specs or that file format in order to have a more robust solution?

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. Unfortunately only the documentation I have is here http://nsidc.org/data/docs/daac/glas_altimetry/gla14_records_r34.html

Comment: @puti Yeah, I read that yesterday. That doesn't really explain the file format. Mostly the "structure" of a record.

Comment: You have reached very near to my problem. Since I put 13760 offsets for header lines, and 176 offsets for binary parts. I could get first few lines of i_lat exactly. But I could not determine the counts of i_lat. I know they are 15312. But how to know from the binary file...

Comment: If you have time, I think you can understand the file format from the idl programs they provide to read the data. The file type is gla14. ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/icesat/tools/idl/reader/isips/IDLreadGLAS_20140731/

Comment: @puti I'm stupid ( <-- this is my word of the day). But this time really stupid: the answer was right in front of my eyes since yesterday !

Comment: I hope you have now mastered the binary files

Comment: @SylvainLeroux please elaborate! I want to know the answer now! I was going to suggest an heuristic, but your answer was along the lines of what I had thought of.

Comment: did you also know how to get the size of i_lat i.e., 15312?

Comment: @bconstanzo Let me the time to write the answer! Well, this is done now -- check below . At puti: _"how to get the size of i_lat i.e., 15312"_ I won't have time to check for that. Sorry.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux thank you very much for your valuable time today. i hope we can meet again.